# Java ASM: Cant Instantiate ClassNode

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I am using ASM v5.0.3.  I am trying to create a ClassNode but the constructor appears to hang forever.  Here is the code:

```
    logger.warn("______ Creating class node");
    try {
        logger.warn("______ Creating class node 1");
        ClassNode classNode = new ClassNode();
        logger.warn("______ Creating class node 2");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.error("Could not instantiate class node");
    }
    logger.warn("______ Created class node");
```

On the console I see

```
WARN 2014-10-29 17:06:37,704 [line 39] ______ Creating class node
WARN 2014-10-29 17:06:37,704 [line 42] ______ Creating class node 1
```

And then nothing else.  I am at a total loss as to whats happening here.  How would I go about diagnosing and fixing this?  Has anyone seen this before.  The other thing I have been doing to try to solve the issue is to remove old versions of asm from transitive dependencies, such as:

```xml
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

Since I am using

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm-all</artifactId>
    <version>${ow2.asm.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: try `catch (Throwable e)` instead

Comment: have you tried ``new ClassNode(Opcodes.ASM5)`` ?

Comment: I looked in the source code and thats supposed to be the default.  Let me add it explicitly and get right back.

Comment: Still no go.  I cant even tell if the thread just dies or if it is hanging.  jstack on the JPS pid does not appear to contain useful information.